# Highcharts: Bar chart: Label width : nowrap

Tags: highcharts

Thanks for your help.  I have having a heck of a time trying to get something to work which is throwing me for a loop..

As seen in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q9rkq25n/) (code copied below) i have a bar chart with a really long label which is wrapping.

What i am hoping to do i max out the label portion of the chart so that the label doesn't wrap while reducing the size of the actual data chart.

As an example; in the jsfiddle the label is maybe 30% of the total width and the bar data is 70%.  Knowing my data, the labels would take up 80% of the width and the data would be in the last 20%.

Thoughts?  Thanks, Steven.

```js
$(function () {

$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: { type: 'bar' },
    xAxis: {           
        labels: {
            style: {
                "textOverflow": "none",
            }
    } ,
    categories: ['Jan is the first month of the year and if you have a problem with that', 'Feb is the second']
    },
    series: [{  data: [29.9, 71.5] }]
});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, looks like I got what i was looking for.  Hope this helps someone else.

The key for me was setting the maringLeft attribute on the chart:

```js
chart: {
      type: 'bar',
      marginLeft: 460
},
```

That, along with modifying the width, 'min-width' and useHTML on the label and lable style for the xAxis (Bar chart)

```js
xAxis: {
        categories: ['Short Name', 'Much Longer Location Name and if it is true then cool and if you want'],
         labels: {
            style: {
                width: '400px',
                'min-width': '350px'
            },
            useHTML : true
        }
    },
```

Thanks, Steven.